# Android XML Bug

Tags: android, xml

Reformat code in xml change UI Layout
[Before Reformat code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1OgS.png)

[After Reformat code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WVe3.png)

Please help me.

Comment: what code? show before and after

Answer (score 0):

Just go to-:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML-> Set From -> Predefined Style > Android.
```

if doesnot happen try fresh install not updating android studio.